Homotopy groups of H-space are independent of the choice of the base points
Suppose we have two spaces $X$ and $Y$, both of which are weak equivalent(or homotopy equivalent, if you prefer) to H-spaces. Now we have a continuous map $f: X \to Y$  such that $f(x_0)=y_0$ and
$$
f_*: \pi_n(X, x_0) \to \pi_n(Y, y_0)
$$
are isomorphisms for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
How can we prove that $f$ is a weak equivalence? My guess is that the choice of base points are independent, but how can we prove this?
The example I need is $n$-levels of spectrification of spectra. Can anyone say something in this particular case?

You want to show that the connected components of $X$ resp. $Y$ are all weakly equivalent.

@Thorgott Could you please elaborate more on this? Thank you.

Sorry, on second look, what you're asking for just isn't true. Take $Y$ to be any disconnected $H$-space, $X$ the component of its identity and $f$ the inclusion.

You should spell out the special case you're interested in, or better, ask a new question about it.

@BenSteffan I have posted a new question, thank you.

@Thorgott It seems that the requirement on $\pi_0$ rules out your “counter example”.

Sorry, take $S^1\times\mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow S^1\times\mathbb{Z}/2$ a map that is the identity on the component containing the basepoints and constant (taking value in the respective other component) on the other component.

@Thorgott Thank you for your counter example. Do you have any idea about why this is true for levels of spectrification? In the definition of stable homotopy groups, the base points are always fixed, how can we deduce that morphism after spectrification is level-wise weak equivalence?

I don't know what 'levels of spectrification' are. Is your $f$ perhaps an $H$-map? That would be a sufficient condition.

@Thorgott I mean the $n$-th components of the spectrification of a sequential spectrum.
